# Should I Style the IMG, the Picture, or Both?

Tags: css, image

I'm using a `<picture>` tag (along with an `<img>` and `<source>` tag) to show WebP images with a fallback of showing the `png`/`jpg` version if the browser doesn't support WebP.

Up until now I've been able to just style the `<img>` tag inside the `<picture>`, and ignore styling the `<picture>` itself.  However, I just ran into a weird case.

I have a flexbox with the `<picture>` and a text `<div>`, where the `<div>` has `max-width: 60%;` and the `<img>` has `max-width: 40%;`.  The browser limits the `<img>` to that width ... but not the `<picture>`, which inexplicably grows to `600px`.

Now, I can put a `max-width` on the picture to fix this, but I'm trying to understand:

A) when does a `<picture>` tag decide to become bigger than its child `<img>` tag (when no differently-sized `<source>` tags are used)?

B) is it best practice to duplicate styles on `<img>` and `<picture>`, or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Could you add a runnable  snippet? But have to say I don't understand why it's a surprise that the picture grew. Wouldn't the flex just make it take up any spare space that the text element isn't using? Depends on exactly how you've set the CSS I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your html like this?

```
<div>

   <picture>
      <img />
   </picture>

   <div>
      some text
   </div>

</div>
```

If this is the case, you probably need to set the max-width to the "picture" instead of the "img".

Comment: Can you please help explain when the `<picture>` tag takes on the styles of its child `<img>` and when you need to style the `<picture>` specifically?

Comment: Can you give an example of the CSS code that would accompany this HTML to answer the OP's question?

Comment: @machineghost Since ```<picture>``` is the direct child of the wrapper div, we need to limit the width of ```<picture>``` instead of the child of ```<picture>```.

Comment: @cklimowski Thanks for the tip.

If the HTML is the way I said, then the css should be like this:

'
.wrapper-div {
   display: flex;
}

picture {
   flex-grow: 3;
}

.child-div {
   flex-grow: 2;
}
'
flex-grow is the property we should use in this case. And the ratio between picture and child-div should be 6 : 4 ( 3 : 2 ).